# Why, the output is 6 and not 7?

Tags: c, operators, sequence-points

The following C code executes correctly but not as expected. Post increment operator here in `z=z++` is creating confusion here. I may not be able to figure out silly mistake/concept,  Can I have a brief explanation or some helpful link please.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        int x=5,y=6,z=7;
        if(x-y)

            z=z++;
            z=--z;

        printf("%d",z);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to do `z=z++;` because between 2 sequence points you are not allowed to assign a variable 2 times.

This one is a full expression in which you assign z 2 times.  So it can be interpreted ambigously and the result of the C abstract machine is [undefined behavior](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/BB.+Definitions#BB.Definitions-undefinedbehavior).

The same for `z=--z`.

Comment: Thank you, i got your point. You also mean that the answer will depend on compiler.

Comment: Just one doubt, if I have to pick one value from 6, 7 and 8. Which one will be more general and expected answer?

Comment: @skyconfusion This is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You can't rely on any value.